# Was ist Wumms oder Doppelwumms?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In den Deutschen Medien ist diesen Tagen von einem *Wumms* oder einen\m *Doppelwumms* die Rede.  Aber was ist ein *Wumms*?  Das Wort taucht (noch?) nicht im Duden auf, zumindest nicht in der Gratisversion online.  Einige Beispiele:

> Eine Strompreisbremse wird bereits vorbereitet. So ist es im dritten Entlastungspaket vereinbart. Hinzu soll nun noch eine Bremse für den Gaspreis kommen. Bundeskanzler Olaf Scholz spricht deshalb von einem **„Doppel-Wumms“**.

*Quelle: [Doppel-Wumms: Wie die Gaspreisbremse funktionieren könnte](https://www.vorwaerts.de/artikel/doppel-wumms-gaspreisbremse-funktionieren-koennte)*

> Der Kanzler spricht von einem **„Doppel-Wumms“** – aus Sicht von Experten braucht es einen **Wumms** aber auch gerade beim Energiesparen.

*Quelle: [„Doppel-Wumms“ mit Tücken: die Winter-Sorgen des Robert Habeck](https://www.tagesspiegel.de/politik/doppel-wumms-mit-tucken-die-winter-sorgen-des-robert-habeck-8707633.html)*

> Die Krisenpolitik der Ampel: Es hat **Doppel-Wumms** gemacht

*Quelle: [Die Krisenpolitik der Ampel: Es hat Doppel-Wumms gemacht](https://www.welt.de/podcasts/machtwechsel/article241315467/Podcast-Die-Krisenpolitik-der-Ampel-Es-hat-Doppel-Wumms-gemacht.html)*

Das Wort *Wumms* erzielt 1.6 Millionen Ergebnisse bei Google, die scheinen aber im Kontext nicht relevant. Da finde ich zum Beispiel [*Wumms ist das Sport-Satire Format mit Bumms*](https://www.zdf.de/funk/wumms-1052), was nicht gerade weiterhilft.

Laut [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wumms&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=31&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwumms%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwumms%3B%2Cc0) hat die Häufigkeit des Wortes seit ca. 2006 deutlich zugenommen:

[image]
Was ist hier gemeint?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bei dem Wort "Wumms" handelt es sich um ein sogenanntes "onomatopoetisches" oder auch "lautmalerisches" Wort.

[Onomatopoesie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoesie) beschreibt die Bildung von Worten anhand des Klanges, den sie verursachen. Der "Wumms" oder auch "Bums" beschreibt einen sehr lauten Knall oder Aufprall / Aufschlag.

Ein solcher Knall erschreckt als plötzliches Ereignis und schreckt damit die Leute auf.

Ein Wumms ist also im übertragenen Sinn die Beschreibung für ein einschneidendes Ereignis, das aufschreckt / aufmerksam macht. Und der "Doppel-Wumms" würde von mir als eine typische Übertreibung zur besonderen Betonung des Begriffes interpretiert werden.

Allerdings wurde ich in den Kommentaren von O.R. Mapper hingewiesen, dass es in diesem Fall einen konkreten Bezug auf die Stärke des "Wumms" in Form der dahinterliegenden finanziellen Mittel bezieht. Diesbezüglich verweise ich auf die [Antwort von Jonathan Scholbach](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/71834/22560), der diesen Zusammenhang sehr genau herausstellt.

Comment: 'Und der "Doppel-Wumms" ist eine typische Übertreibung zur besonderen Betonung des Begriffes.' - na ja, nicht ganz. Damit ist im hier gegebenen Kontext ganz konkret die Kombination aus genau zwei "Wummsen" gemeint (die mehr oder weniger gleichzeitig auftreten).

Answer (score 6):

Wie Tode bereits richtig feststellt, ist *Wumms* eine lautmalerische Bildung. Dabei wird der Laut einer Explosion imitiert. Verwandt sind die Ausdrücke *Wumme* ("Pistole", "Handfeuerwaffe") und *Kawumm* (Lautnachahmung einer Explosion).

Ein *Wumms* bezeichnet etwas "kraftvolles". Man kann etwa sagen:

> Der Stürmer hämmert den Ball mit Wumms ins Tor.

Schließlich hat der Begriff im Jahr 2022 eine besondere Bedeutung in der politischen Kommunikation erhalten:

Der deutsche Bundeskanzler Olaf Scholz hat im Frühjahr 2022 die Sonderausgabe für die Bundeswehr i.H.v. 100 Milliarden Euro als *Wumms* bezeichnet und die geplante Sonderausgabe für den Gaspreisdeckel und flankierende Maßnahmen i.H.v. 200 Milliarden Euro als *Doppel-Wumms*. Er hat damit also geprägt, dass ein *Wumms* 100 Milliarden Euro sind.

Answer (score 3):

Auf die lautmalerische Herkunft des Wortes wurde bereits hingewiesen, deshalb möchte ich nur ergänzen, daß die Endung *-s* bei solchen Bildungen öfters auftritt, entweder bloß verstärkend oder nominalisierend.

- [bum](https://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB2?lemid=B06004), [bums](https://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB2?lemid=B06017), [der Bums](https://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB2?lemid=B06018)
- [plumps](https://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemid=P05831)
- [knack](https://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemid=K08426), [knacks](https://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemid=K08447), [der Knacks](https://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemid=K08448)
- [wumm](https://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemid=W27720) (auch verbal: [wummern](https://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemid=W27724))

Es geht um Maßnahmen, die wie Granaten einschlagen. Diese militärische Metaphorik hat man oft: [Scholz will klotzen, nicht kleckern](https://www.zdf.de/nachrichten/politik/scholz-regierungserklaerung-bundestag-ampel-100.html), in Anspielung auf [Guderian](https://de.wikiquote.org/wiki/Heinz_Guderian#:%7E:text=%22Klotzen%2C%20nicht%20Kleckern!%22,286).). Das *Doppel* sind zwei gleichzeitig beschlossene Maßnahmen.

Die Belege aus dem DWB zeigen, daß alle diese Wörter nicht neu sind: der Beleg für *wumm* stammt aus dem ersten Weltkrieg, *bum* dagegen schon dreihundert Jahre früher.

Comment: "die wie Granaten einschlagen. Diese militärische Metaphorik" - es gibt im Deutschen auch andere Redewendungen, die einen plötzlichen, lauten Klang in den Vordergrund stellen, um ein aufschreckendes Ereignis zu beschreiben, wie den "Paukenschlag" - und der scheint mir eher musikalisch als militärisch geprägt zu sein. Ob daher beim Wumms, Bumms oder wie sie alle heißen, assoziationstechnisch Granaten einschlagen, eine Trommel gespielt wird oder man gerade eine Kloschüssel vom Balkon geworfen hat, bleibt damit vermutlich meist dem Zuhörer überlassen.

Answer (score 3):

Das Wort *Wumms* betrat die politische Bühne am 3.6.2020 in einer Pressekonferenz der Bundesregierung zur Corona-Krise. Der damalige Finanzminister Olaf Scholz kündigte damals ein umfassendes Hilfspaket zur Linderung der Corona-Krise an und begann seine Ausführungen mit den Worten

> [Wir wollen mit Wumms aus der Krise kommen](https://www.bundesregierung.de/breg-de/themen/coronavirus/-wir-wollen-mit-wumms-aus-der-krise-kommen--1757510).

Obwohl *Wumms* bis heute nicht in Wörterbüchern wie dem Duden zu finden ist und das Wort im "offiziellen Sprachgebrauch" zuvor vermutlich nicht benutzt wurde, war die Bedeutung im Kontext der Rede offensichtlich: Es sollten erhebliche Finanzmittel zur Linderung der wirtschaftlichen Folgen der Pandemie bereitgestellt werden. Warum *Wumms* mit kraftvollen, spürbaren und durchaus "lauten" Aktionen assoziiert wird, wurde in den anderen Antworten dargelegt.

Das Wort fand seit 2020 Eingang in den politischen und journalistischen Sprachgebrauch und wurde damit sozusagen salonfähig.

Mit dem *Doppel-Wumms* griff Scholz Ende September 2022 den *Wumms* auf und kündigte ein noch größeres Hilfspaket zur Linderung der aktuellen Energiepreiskrise an.

Sieht man sich die Zahlen der Hilfspakete an, könnte man *Wumms* als neue Geldeinheit verstehen: 1 Wumms = 100 Milliarden Euro.

Answer (score 2):

Dabei dürfte es sich im Einzelfall um ein Akronym handeln, dessen eigentliche Bedeutung noch unklar ist,

Ein Akkronyn ist eine Abkürzung, deren Anfangsbuchstaben zusammen als ein Wort gelesen werden, wie bspw. Pin, "Persönliche Identifikationsnummer", GroKo "Große Koalition", lol "laughing out loud", usw. Dabei ist in einer vielzahl der Fälle offensichtlich davon auszugehen, dass eine passende Abkürzung mit Absicht herbeigeführt wurde.

So wird es sich auch hier verhalten. *Wärme* (bzw. *Waren*) und *Umlage* kann man aus dem Zusammenhang heraus bereits erraten. Damit wäre *W.Um.* im Ansatz schon erklärt. Dies liegt im Beamtendeutsch schon *nahe*, seit Einwirkung von Marketingberatern um so näher.

Die Aussprache und dementsprechend die Schreibung suggerieren allerdings, *wumm*, das hier in Frage stehen soll. Zuerst muss man Wissen, dass von der SPD häufig gesagt wird, die Partei würde "umfallen". Was das im Einzelfall heißt, wird anderswo erörtert. Jedenfalls gibt es ein lautes Geräusch, das ungefähr wie ***Wumms*** klingt, jedesmal wenn die Genossen umfallen und der ohnmächtige Körper der Partei auf das politischen Parkett aufschlägt. Vgl. auch zusammenbrechende Kartenhäuser, Domino artige Kettenreaktionen. Umschlagen heißt auch im technischen Sinne *die Richtung wechseln*, bzw. die Art und Weise, so etwa *plötzlich* vom Wetter. Dem steht wiederum der *Umschwung* nahe. Vermutlich hat sich das Labiale */w/ (konsonantisches u) in der anscheinbaren Lautmalerei leichter verteilt und damit länger erhalten, sowie *wham, boom, bang* auf English ganz ähnlich anklingen.

In Anbetracht des sprichwörtlichen Pauken-Schlages stehen sachliche Bezüge an. Auf Schwedisch heißt *påk* oder auch *knölpåk* etwa "Keule" (vgl. En. *whack*, Lat. *bacculum*, usw.)

Lautgesetzlich wäre theoretisch ein Vergleich mit *kaboom* schon ein ganz anderer, denn nebst *zoom* wechselt das k eventuel, so vielleicht auch *tumb, dumpf*. Tatsächlich kann Taubheit als Perfektbildung zu des Schlages Nachwirkung gelten. Die starke Beugung der Verben ist an der Stelle einschlägig, etwa *-im / -am / -um, wie *trinke, Trank, getrunken*. Das hilft aber nicht viel weiter, insofern unterschiedliche Anschlussmöglichkeiten nicht ausgeschlossen werden können.

Besondere Bedeutung hat an der Stelle meines erachtens *umkommen*, denn so ähnlich wie *un-* zu *ne-* steht (bedeutet *negation*), dürfte *um-* zufällig zu *me- gehören, weil die Bedeutung von *mer- hervorragend passt. Das ist die Wortwurzel zu Fr. *mourir* "sterben", wie in Deutsch *Mord*. So wie /r/ im Silbenauslaut vokalisiert wird, schwindet auch das g zuweilen, sodass Metathese zur Nebeform *um(g)e-kommen* wahrscheinlich erscheint, sofern die Englisch Wortbedeutung *become* die ursprünglichnere ist (vgl. *? become dead*, jedoch *come clean*).

Die Itterativbildung steht in der That mit r: *wummernde Kopfschmerzen*. Dementgegen ist eine bloße Interjektion eigentlich durch Pragmatik zu erschließen. Der Doppel-Wumms klingt dahingehend eher nach doppelter Buchführung, *Double Dutch*, *Dutch Sandwich* und *Doppelsprech*. Doppelte Buchführung ist an und für sich nicht schlecht. Irgendwie will man ja erfahren, wer das am Ende alles noch bezahlen soll.

Comment: Interessant, aber, ich bin nicht ganz davon überzeugt, dass *Wumms* hier ein Akronym ist.

Comment: +1 für den Meister des Absurden.

Comment: @gerrit Vgl. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinlaus

Answer (score 0):

Der Duden ist schon lange keine besonders gute Quelle um nach Wörtern zu suchen. Mehr findet man in Wiktionary:

- [Wumms](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wumms)
- [Wums](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wums)

Der Artikel mit der Schreibweise *Wumms* ist nur schlecht belegt. Besser belegt ist *Wums,* und das entspricht auch der Schreibweise, die ich bevorzugen würde. Denn zwei Konstanten am Ende einer Silbe (hier *m* und *s*) signalisieren ohnehin, dass der Vokal kurz auszusprechen ist.

Sonst auch eine sehr gute Resource ist das Digitale Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache (DWDS). Dort finde ich aber weder *Wums* noch *Wumms,* wohl aber den Mehrwortausdruck [Wumms haben](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Wumms%20haben) (Nur mit Doppel-M).

Das Kompositum mit dem Wort *Doppel* dient dazu, die Bedeutung des Ausdrucks verstärken (ein doppelt so heftiger Wums). Damit sind nicht zwei zusammengehörige Exemplare eines Wums gemeint.

---

Das Wort entstammt einem eher umgangssprachlichen Kontext, ist also vorwiegend der gesprochenen Sprache zuzuordnen. Allerdings gibt es in den letzten beiden Jahrzehnten zunehmend die Tendenz, Äußerungen, die der gesprochenen Sprache zuzurechnen sind, auch in der Schriftform zu verwenden. Als Ursache dafür vermute ich das Internet, in dem viel gechatet wird. Chats sind zwar geschriebene Nachrichten, sie ahmen aber sehr stark die gesprochene Sprache nach. Daher steigt - wie ich vermute - allgemein die Bereitschaft, Besonderheiten der gesprochenen Sprache in der Schriftform wiederzugeben.

Und ich vermute weiter, dass genau dieser Umstand der Grund dafür ist, dass man den Wörtern *Wums* und *Wumms* seit kurzem auch in gedruckten Texten begegnet. Denn in der gesprochenen Sprache waren diese Begriffe auch in meiner Kindheit (geboren 1965) schon verbreitet.

[image: Google Ngram: Wums, Wumms; 1950-2019]
<sup>[Quelle](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Wumms%2CWums&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=31&smoothing=3)</sup>

Comment: "Damit sind nicht zwei zusammengehörige Exemplare eines Wums gemeint." - im gegebenen Kontext eigentlich schon, weil es ja eben gerade um zwei zugleich angestoßene Maßnahmen geht (z.B. gemäß [einem der verlinkten Artikel](https://www.vorwaerts.de/artikel/doppel-wumms-gaspreisbremse-funktionieren-koennte) Strompreisbremse + Gaspreisbremse).